# C operators result type

Tags: c, casting

In C11 (n1570), there are some operators whose result types are clearly stated. For example, the result of && has type int.
But I haven't found the result type of other operators, like +. Is it specified somewhere in the standard?

I tried this program:

```
unsigned char usc = 254;
unsigned int usi = 4294967293;
signed char sic = 126;
long long unsigned llu = usc*2;
printf("%llu\n",llu);
llu = usi*2;
printf("%llu\n",llu);
llu = usc+usc;
printf("%llu\n",llu);
llu = usi+usi;
printf("%llu\n",llu);
llu = usc+4294967294;
printf("%llu\n",llu);
llu = usc+2147483646;
printf("%llu\n",llu);
llu = sic+4294967294;
printf("%llu\n",llu);
llu = sic+2147483646;
printf("%llu\n",llu);
```

Output:

```
508
4294967290
508
4294967290
4294967548
18446744071562068220
4294967420
18446744071562068092
```

I guess unsigned char gets promoted here, but unsigned int doesn't; result type of char + unsigned int seems to be unsigned int, and result type of char + int seems to be int.

But I'm not so sure.

Are these castings standard, or implementation-defined?

Comment: 6.3.1.8 has all the answers for you.

Comment: I'd say these two: `llu = usc+2147483646;` and `llu = sic+2147483646;`, are implementation defined since an int result wraps and is then assigned to llu.

Comment: @this The second line is already implementation-defined. `unsigned int` is not required to be wider than 16-bit, and thus the line `unsigned int usi = 4294967293;` assigns `usi` with a value that depends on the implementation-defined definition of `UINT_MAX`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Sure, I was assuming int is 32bit everywhere today.

Comment: @this Assume makes an ass out of u and me... Know that one? There are many modern machines where `int` is not 32 bits, especially embedded ones. AFAICT, they still vastly outnumber those where that's the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rules are explicitly defined by the standard:

> #### 6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions
>
> 1 Many operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause conversions and yield result
>   types in a similar way. The purpose is to determine a common real type for the operands
>   and result. For the specified operands, each operand is converted, without change of type
>   domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is the common real type. Unless
>   explicitly stated otherwise, the common real type is also the corresponding real type of
>   the result, whose type domain is the type domain of the operands if they are the same,
>   and complex otherwise. This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions:
>
> - First, if the corresponding real type of either operand is long double, the other
>     operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is long double.
> - Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is double, the other
>     operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose
>     corresponding real type is double.
> - Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is float, the other
>     operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose
>     corresponding real type is float.62)
> - Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then the
>     following rules are applied to the promoted operands:
>
>   - If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.
>   - Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned
>       integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank is
>       converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.
>   - Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
>       equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
>       signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
>       integer type.
>   - Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent
>       all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, then
>       the operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the type of the
>       operand with signed integer type.
>   - Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type
>       corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

Still, how big your types are and whether signed types use 1s-complement, 2s-complement or sign-and-magnitude representation is implementation-defined.

You properly deduced what happens for your implementation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no “casting” in your examples, only conversions. A *cast* is a syntactic construct, like `(unsigned long)`, that causes a conversion. Conversions also happen on their own, as they do in your examples.

The names for the conversions that happen in your examples is **“usual arithmetic conversions”**. They are described in the C11 standard at clause 6.3.1.8, which is too long to quote in full (it also handles the conversion from integer type to floating-point type when the program contains `1 + 1.0`). For integer types, the rules look like:

> If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is
>   needed.
>
> Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both
>   have unsigned integer types, the operand with the type of lesser
>   integer conversion rank is converted to the type of the operand with
>   greater rank.
>
> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type
>   has rank greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other
>   operand, then the operand with signed integer type is converted to the
>   type of the operand with unsigned integer type.
>
> Otherwise, if the type
>   of the operand with signed integer type can represent all of the
>   values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, then the
>   operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the type of the
>   operand with signed integer type.
>
> Otherwise, both operands are
>   converted to the unsigned integer type corresponding to the type of
>   the operand with signed integer type.

**The type of the result is the same as the common type decided for the operands.**

[Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/)'s front-end, which is only one “apt-get install” away if you are using Linux, makes these conversions explicit and displays them as casts when you command it to print the Abstract Syntax Tree it has built. On your examples, the conversions are (removing the `printf()` calls that do not add information):

```
$ frama-c -print t.c
...
  usc = (unsigned char)254;
  usi = 4294967293;
  sic = (signed char)126;
  llu = (unsigned long long)((int)usc * 2);
  llu = (unsigned long long)(usi * (unsigned int)2);
  llu = (unsigned long long)((int)usc + (int)usc);
  llu = (unsigned long long)(usi + usi);
  llu = (unsigned long long)((unsigned int)usc + 4294967294);
  llu = (unsigned long long)((int)usc + 2147483646);
  llu = (unsigned long long)((unsigned int)sic + 4294967294);
  llu = (unsigned long long)((int)sic + 2147483646);
```

This is for a common ILP32 architecture. Implementation-defined parameters can influence the conversions, as for instance the type of `40000` may be `int` for most C99 compilers and `long int` with others (it is always the first type in the list `int`, `long int`, `long long int` that can represent the constant).

Comment: In your `llu = (unsigned long long)((unsigned int)usc + 4294967294);` example. 4294967294 is of type long long int not unsigned int, 4294967294u would be an unsigned int.  usc gets promoted to long long int. What do you think?

Comment: @this If you do not use any particular option such as `-std=c99`, GCC still applies C90 rules for integer constants. With these rules and 32-bit int/unsigned int, `4294967294` gets typed as `unsigned long` (C90 did not have `long long` but the list of types to try for integer constants ended in `unsigned long`. Frama-C uses these rules  in order to follow what GCC does without options. (“The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can be represented.  Unsuffixed decimal: int, long int, unsigned long int …” — http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt )

Comment: Ok, but we are talking about standard not compilers, under c11 and 32bit int, 4294967294 is long long int, right?

Comment: @this Yes, in C11 and if both `int` and `long` are 32-bit wide, `4294967294` gets typed as `long long`.